# Добрый день ошибка при отправке данных с формы This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, сервер, express, ispmanager

добрый день отправляю данные формы пост запросом с сайта на сервер node.js запущен он у меня на 3000 порту.

на локальном хосте всё работало без проблем. да и если через постман отправляю запросы и они проходят, а вот когда сайт выложил на сервер, при отправке данных формы получаю ошибку

This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[image: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.]

Я так понимаю ошибка связана с тем что запрос отправлен не на защищённый сервер https

как в таком случае настроить серверную часть приложения ?

приложение на сервере элементарное просто получаю запрос и отправляю его в тг

[image: приложение]